# Do head-shots always kill in one shot?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

I'm talking about Tomb Raider multiplayer. I'm getting the sense that, similarly to Battlefield 2, instead of a headshot dealing 100% damage or otherwise setting the targeted player as dead, headshots merely deal extra damage. Which is the case?

This is important because it determines whether or not that I should focus solely on higher-skill-ceiling accuracy and firing-rate stats (relying on getting headshots), or try to balance these with damage for the weapons that I use if not enough damage means the head-shots won't even kill in one shot anyway.

What about uncharged competition bow headshot? What about a fully charged non-competition bow headshot against a player with the skill that reduces arrow damage? And analogical situations with other weapons?

Answer (score -2):

I think it has to do with the weapons upgrades (and the enemy).  The make shift longbow rarely seems to kill with a head shot, but some of the later bows will.  Same goes for the trench shotgun vs upgraded ones.  The other factor are skills upgrades.

Of course, as the weapons improve the enemies seem to get tougher too.

Comment: They mean in multiplayer not story